# app not recogonizing user as admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created user roles, however my app is not picking up that my account is a admin. It shows the role as admin but then admin is also nil.

From rails console:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > user = User.find(13)
  User Load (17.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 13 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 13, admin: nil, role: "admin", roles_mask: nil> 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > user.roles
 => [] 
2.0.0-p0 :003 > user.role?(:admin)
 => false
```

If it's understanding the users role is admin, how come it is not accepting it as admin and giving the account the proper permissions? I need this fixed as I am trying to allow only admins to modify all profiles, and then specifying regular users to only be able to modify and access their own profiles.

user.rb:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :password_confirmation, :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

Comment: isn't it wrong to `user.roles` return `[]` ?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why it return a bracket.

Comment: Will a user belong to multiple roles?

Comment: what 'user.role' return? => admin :)

Comment: I think it would be a lot better if you create a relation between users and roles and also check cancan(https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) it will make your life easier =)

Comment: User will have 1 role only. User.role returns admin.

Comment: All users in the application?!

Comment: Then why worry about a role mask? If you are using cancan (which I'm assuming you are since the role mask code is straight from the wiki) you can define your ability by making an `admin` boolean attribute and checking with `user.admin?` or following the [One role per user](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) recommendation.

Comment: Users will not be a moderator or admin, and vice versa. Users will be able to edit their profile and message users. Admin will be able to edit all profiles and message all users. I previously used Cancan which is why it's probably there, but I want to build from scratch so I can learn how it all functions as I'm new to Rails. I though I removed the cancan files, so I will get that out now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment,

```
user.role
=> admin
```

So, you can add to your application_controller something like:

```
def admin
  unless current_user.role == 'admin'
    flash[:error] = "Authorisation is required to access this content."
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

In this way, you can block users that are not admin to access some action in a controller:

```
before_filter :admin, :only => [:destroy]
```

It is just one example to give you some direction, and I am assuming you have current_user helper.

I hope it helps...